# GitLab CI Runner, how to use volumes or mounts in service containers

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I use GitLab CI Runner, it uses the command:

```
docker run -d --name postgres postgres:9.4
```

I want to do something like this:

```
docker run -d --name postgres --volumes-from postgres_datastore postgres:9.4
```

But GitLab CI Runner doesn't support any options `(-v or --volumes-from)`.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I have similar issue. Spent the whole day in Gitlab runner ci/cd trying to find out how I can mount src:target volumes onto an IMAGE:my-bespoke-image that I am using in my gitlab runner script. No where closer to finding out. Have upvoted your question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Docker `volumes-from` option is not yet available in Gitlab CI Runner (see this [PR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/131)), however you can configure host mounts and volumes:

```
[runners.docker]
  volumes = ["/host/path:/target/path:rw", "/some/path"]
```

The above example would mount `/host/path` at `/target/path/` inside the container and also create a new volume container at `/some/path`.

See the Gitlab CI Runner [manual](https://github.com/ayufan/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section) for all docker related options.

**Edit**:

For service containers it seems you can only define volumes via the dockerfile of the service image. Maybe enough depending on your requirements.

Comment: Your example would mount path inside general runner-container (not container with postgres-service).

Comment: Correct, your question was a bit misleading. I updated the title and answer, hopefully clearer now.

Comment: In Gitlab CI Runner - where would that snippet detailing [runners.docker] ..... etc. 
Where would it go ?
And, would those volumes be mounted on the image running from IMAGE: etc. etc. in our .gitlab-ci.yml script ?

Comment: @user1561783, you can write it at `config.toml` runner config file. See this: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#volumes-in-the-runnersdocker-section