# In which path does docker and docker-in-docker run its containers?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I have a dockerized nginx server which I can build and run on my local machine without any problems. So now I want to deploy this with the help of a gitlab runner.

This is my simple dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY web /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

So if I build and run this on my local machine, it works. But I have a first question at this point: Where does docker run the nginx server? Because if I look at /usr/share there is nothing there.

Now if I push my project to gitlab, register a runner and let it execute the following gitlab-ci file:

```
image: docker:stable

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  script:
    - docker build -t bd24_nginx .
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 bd24_nginx
```

... the job gets done just fine. There are no errors in the console output of the gitlab page. This is the output:

```
Successfully built 9903dc370422
Successfully tagged bd24_nginx:latest
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 bd24_nginx
b1e24c7cf9af8a43b3c2418d1ca1b90a58e445eb6b0b0ac9cde61f99be8cff7b
Job succeeded
```

But if I now visit the ip address of my server, the static html test page doesn't show up. So I suspect there is something wrong with the paths? Or is there anything I am missing completely?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using docker means the data are copied in the corresponding container. When docker has finished running, the container does not keep any data.

You might try to mount some host directory to the docker in order to have a persistent storage.
See [this answer for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36607188/9890401).

Hope this helps!